# how to get record of last 3 month's in Yii1 using criteria?

Tags: php, yii

I trying to get record of last 3 month's. I have current data & time, and added_date of record.

I try like this

```
$criteria->condition = "registered >= ".date('Y-m-d h:i:s',(strtotime ( '-3 month' , strtotime ($now))));
```

but it given error
[image]

please give me right suggestion or answer.
thanks!

Comment: 'registered' is my added_date database field and $now is current date and time (date('Y-m-d h:i:s')).

Comment: please give datatype of added_date?

Comment: database field name is 'registered' and datatype is datetime already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You are replacing the original condition and not removing the parameter ':uid' hence the error.
2. The datetime is not being quoted properly.

Use the [`CDbCriteria::addCondition()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) function as you can add the date as a parameter and have Yii quote it for you:

```
$criteria->addCondition('registered >= :registered');
$criteria->params[':registered'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-3 month'));
```

Comment: I already use -  $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition'=>'t.user_id=:uid',
            'params'=>array(
                ':uid'=>Yii::app()->user->model->id
            ),
        ));

how to add new condition with my old condition ?

Comment: when I use your condition then it's given "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: I've updated the answer. For future reference this additional information should be included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this solution for your problem :

```
$model = new Modelname();
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', (strtotime('-3 month')));
$criteria->condition = "registered >= ".$date;
$criteria->addCondition = 'user_id=:userID';
$criteria->params = array(':user_id' => Yii::app()->user->model->id);
$res = $model->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: can I add condition in with .....like :- 
.
.
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition'=>'t.user_id=:uid',
            'params'=>array(
                ':uid'=>Yii::app()->user->model->id
            ),
        ));

Comment: when I remove date('Y-m-d h:i:s') h:i:s then it work, but I want work with time, and most probably I want condition like upper comment.

Comment: you can check now.